# Конвертировать черно-белое изображение малого размера в матрицу того же размера на C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Допустим есть черно-белое изображение размера 10x10 пикселей, то его нужно перевести в матрицу 10x10 в которой черному цвету будет соответствовать 1, а белому 0 или можно использовать 1 и -1 не важно собственно (что-то из этого). Желательно на языке C++.

```
unsigned char* readBMP(const char* filename)
{
int i;
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
unsigned char info[54];
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

// extract image height and width from header
int width = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];

int size = 3 * width * height;
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
fclose(f);

for (i = 0; i < size; i += 3)
{
    unsigned char tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[i + 2];
    data[i + 2] = tmp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        cout << "R: " << (int)data[3 * (i * width + j)] << "; G: " << (int)data[3 * (i * width + j) + 1] << "; B: " << (int)data[3 * (i * width + j) + 2] << endl;
    }
}

return data;
}
```

Comment: Какую библиотеку для работы с изображениями вы используете? И какой формат изображений?

Comment: У вас есть доступ к пикселам изображения?

Comment: вот такой код использовал для чтения bmp черно-белого

Comment: Только код для чтения цветного изображения.

Comment: Код предназначен для чтения 24-бит битмапа, и он некорректный - даст сбои, если ширина не кратна 4. Но xто мешает подогнать эту оcнову под нужный формат?

Comment: Ок, спасибо за подсказку. В принципе я уже добился чего хотел.